# Некластерный индекс уникальный или нет

Tags: sql-server

Объясните пожалуйста, Есть ли смысл ставить некластерный индекс для столбца FK, в котором могут повторяться значения? И если да, то когда есть смысл ставить  некластерный индекс(в плане количества строк), а когда лучше оставить без индекса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если строк мало то оптимизатор индекс не выберет для работы, с другой стороны если строк мало, то индекс будет занимать копейки места и его наличие  будет не заметно. С другой стороны, когда количество строк со временем вырастет, все уже забудут, что индекса нет и начнутся проблемы.

А от того колонка FK или нет, необходимость индекса никак не зависит. Индекс нужен что бы быстро искать. Перед созданием индекса задайте себе вопрос, как часто происходит поиск по данному полю явно или не явно (например удаление записей в таблице на которую ссылается FK захочет проверить, не осталось ли записей с удаляемым значением в таблице и индекс ему бы в этом помог). Так же стоит обратить внимание, что если между двумя таблицами есть связь, потребовавшая создания FK, то очень вероятно, что эти таблицы будут в запросах объединять JOIN и тогда наличие индекса будет очень полезно.

Comment: насколько мне известно большое количество повторяющихся значений ухудшает работу индекса так ли это?

Comment: @Geminy1653 Работу самого индекса это не ухудшает. Вопрос в том, что поднятие даже одной строки с диска с использованием индекса медленнее чем без него. Но только без индекса для поиска даже одной строки надо пересмотреть всю таблицу. Если у вас скажем 2 млн строк, из которых 1 млн имеет значение '1' и вы его ищите по индексу, то поднятие млн строк по индексу будет гораздо дольше, чем просмотр всей таблицы. Поэтому есть понятие 'селективность индекса', это какой процент таблицы занимает наиболее частое значение. Если более 10% от всех записей - то индекс может быть вреден